# IIS Handler, Delphi to C# conversion

Tags: c#, delphi

I am currently converting a Delphi application to C# for an ISS Handler.Delphi uses these memory classes (TMemoryStream, TStreamAdapter) to pass to methods, insert string values, and return and retrieve values from memory.
My question here is, do i really need to create memory objects to insert string values and pass them through methods for retrieval, or is this just unique to the Delphi handler. Currently i am just passing and retrieving string values in my ISS handler, will this be a sort of correct conversion.
Ive researched and came up short. Your help is kindly appreciated.

for eg Delphi code:

```
    m := TMemoryStream.Create;
    iss := TStreamAdapter.Create(m, soOwned);
    iss._AddRef;

    try
      hr := CAGetPath(cas, cam, cal, iss);
      cb := 0;
       m.Write(cb, sizeof(WideChar));
       s := PWideChar(m.Memory);
    finally
      iss._Release;
    end;

    function CAGetPath(SubscriberID, MailshotID, LinkID: integer;
      stmPath: ISequentialStream): HRESULT; stdcall;
    {
        sPath: WideString;
        sPath := "\\MYPATH\\TO\\FOLDER"
        stmPath._AddRef;
        cb := length(sPath) * sizeof(WideChar);
        ES := 'stmPath.Write(' + sPath + ')';
        Result := stmPath.Write(PWideChar(sPath), cb, nil);

    }
```

This bit of delphi code just returns a string and sets it to variable s. As fas as i can tell. Is this  neccessary and why would anyone do it this way?

Comment: Impossible to say. You don't actually tell us what the goal is. So, how can we know what the best way to solve the problem and implement that solution?

Comment: It would really help if you posted real code and refrained from posting fake code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the only fake code there is the assignment of string sPath. That calls a datalayer method which retrieves the path from database using the int input parameters

Comment: The implementation of `CAGetPath` is fake.

Comment: From what I can see, you are attempting to code up something very simple. Just code it using idiomatic C#. Don't try to copy the Delphi implementation. Understand what the Delphi code does, if you need to reproduce its behaviour. But write a clean C# implementation that uses the natural idiom of that language, and also performs the right operations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for your time and advice. Just wondered if using  memorystreams is important for iss handlers, because of memory leaks or something to that effect, not sure. Thanks again.

Comment: What's important is to get the code to do what you need it to do. The memory stream is used because the author wanted an implementation of `IStream`. And used `TStreamAdapter` which needs a `TStream` to wrap. And hence the simplest concrete `TStream`, the `TMemoryStream`. All the code is doing is asking `CAGetPath` to provide a URL. Do that in the most convenient way in your C# program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I really need to create memory objects to insert string values and pass them through methods for retrieval, or is this just unique to the Delphi handler?

The author of the Delphi code is best placed to explain why it was done in that particular way. However, it looks to me as though `CAGetPath` is an external function since it was declared using `stdcall`. And so the author will have needed to come up with a solid means to marshal text data across a module boundary. The author chose to use the COM `ISequentialStream` interface which is a perfectly reasonable choice.

In order to interact with that from Delphi, the author needed to use an object that implements `ISequentialStream`. The simplest way is to use the `TStreamAdapter` class which wraps a `TStream` and presents an `IStream` interface. In order to use that, a concrete stream must be provided. Hence the use of `TMemoryStream`. Clearly `CAGetPath` must return the URL somewhere and why not a memory stream?

Anyway, that's my best guess as to why the Delphi code is that way. There's no evidence that memory streams are needed to implement IIS handlers (whatever they are).

I think you are getting all hung up on replicating the Delphi implementation. In your shoes I would simply try to understand what the underlying requirements are. What is your IIS handler required to do? Then implement that using the idiomatic C# techniques and classes. Use the extant Delphi code as a guide of *what* the requirement is, but not as a guide for *how* to implement that requirement.